# Spree active record object nil when eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, spree

I'm trying to query item and loop through them. The `li` is not nil but accessing `product` on it throws NilClass error.

```
Spree::LineItem.includes(:product).where(order_id: oids).find_each do |li|
  unless li.nil?
    unless li.product.nil?
      puts li.product.id
    end
  end
end
```

This throws the error on line number `3`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `product' for nil:NilClass
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spree_core-3.0.0/app/models/spree/line_item.rb:95:in `product'
from (irb):5:in `block in irb_binding'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:51:in `each'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:51:in `block in find_each'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:124:in `find_in_batches'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:50:in `find_each'
from (irb):3
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

As we see we have already checked that `li` is not nil. I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: full stacktrace pls, I think the error came from another place

Comment: +1, that your code is ok and there shouldn't be any errors. Please paste full LineItem model code, full method code, where you call this piece and full stacktrace

Comment: not sure `find_each` used like this is correct. Have you tried with `each` instead ?

Comment: yes, I did that. :) Doesn't work. I'll add the requested details to the question asap.

Comment: @HieuPham I think you were correct that the error is coming from somewhere else. I've updated the question.

Comment: @aks still can't find it out :( :(

Comment: btw did you check the source code at /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spree_core-3.0.0/app/models/spree/line_item.rb:95

Comment: @HieuPham Nope, I haven't checked the source code yet, I'll do that.